# Crystal Report Engine error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

i am stuck with a problem regarding Crystal Report 13. I am working on Visual Studio 2013 developing Web Application.

Previously i've developed reports and those were working fine but after some time on web page crystal report viewer stop rendering. I tried to resolve the issue by suggestions on different forums where i need to add reference of Crystal Report 13 files in my Web.Config. After all changes the problem was not resolved. Than people suggested me to re-install redistribution package of crystal report 13, i've done the same thing now there is a new problem which is quite different. Whenever i am trying to open page it shows following error:

```
Server Error in '/Abcd' Application.
The document has not been opened.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The document has not been opened.
```

I've tried many forums and different suggestions but all seems useless, i've check the appropriate rights even try after giving full rights but still at same position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the alternative solution, before i was using 13.0.21 redistribution package which was using registry dlls version 13.0.2000.0, i was facing two problems using that particular version.
1. Unable to edit rpt file, whenever i tried to open it an error appear on screen that The operations is failed or unable to complete operation (something like that i don't know exactly what the error is but the summary is this)
2. When i try to open Crystal report viewer during execution, i've come up with error which i posted earlier.

What i have done for the resolution, that i've download Crystal report developer version 13.0.21 and install it with "Run as Administrator" because i creates some entries in your registry of windows, keep in your mind to close VS during installation. After successful installation both problems are solved but u need to change the dlls version in your code from 13.0.2000.0 to 13.0.3500.0